# cost of throwing exceptions in Scala

Tags: scala, exception, throw

Is it expensive to throw exceptions in Scala?

More specifically, when mapping exceptions for a future call such as:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val fut: Future[Int] = Future(1)
```

is there much difference between `x` and `y` in terms of performance?

```
case class MappedException(message: String) extends Exception(message)

val x = fut.recover {
  case e => throw MappedException(e.getMessage)
}

val y = fut.recoverWith {
  case e => Future.failed(MappedException(e.getMessage))
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is "much" difference regarding expensiveness (would be much surprised if any exception handling / stack unwinding overhead is not dwarfed by all the "mapping" ). The second seems more idiomatic stylistically (you don't want to `throw` Exceptions in Scala, you want to return failures). I suspect the end result is identical for both.

Comment: Only a microbenchmark can provide a definitive answer. However, as pointed out by Josh Bloch in _Effective Java_ (item 69, 3rd ed.), using exceptions for control flow (as you do for computing `x`) can lead to bad performance. The way you compute `y` is—I'm only guessing—more efficient than the way you compute `x`, and, at any rate, more idiomatic Scala code. Treat exceptions as values rather than throw them.

Comment: The title is misleading, what you are really asking is whats the difference between `Future.apply` and `Future.failed` (or `Future.successful`). The second is more efficient so `y` should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there will be much difference.

You should measure it for yourself though: https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh

> JMH is a Java harness for building, running, and analysing nano/micro/milli/macro benchmarks written in Java and other languages targeting the JVM.